# Jquery auto sliding lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have here a slider, built only with HTML and CSS, but it's not auto sliding.
I thought maybe some Jquery will help.

I have a Fade In, Fade Out function but it it's turning the black background while it's changing. And I don't like that!

```
    function InOut(elem) {
    var delayOn = 3000, // time each <li> should be visible
        delayOff = 0, // time between revealing each <li>
        fade = 1000; // fade duration

    // Pause, fade in, pause again, fadeout, then fire the callback
    elem.delay(delayOff).fadeIn(fade).delay(delayOn).fadeOut(function() {
        // If we're not on the last <li>
        if (elem.next().length > 0) {
            // Call InOut on the next <li>
            InOut(elem.next());
        }
        else {
            // Else go back to the start
        InOut(elem.siblings(':first'));
        }
    });
}

$(function() {
    // Hide all the li's
    $('#slider li').hide();
    // Call InOut to loop through them
    InOut($('#slider li:first'));
});
```

Please look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8FzR9/) and let me know how I can do this, a sliding animation will work also, thanks!

PS: If you want to look how is sliding only with CSS, just delete de JS function!

Comment: What exactly is the issue you're trying to solve? Is it the slider fading to the black background?

Comment: yes, I don't want to turn black background... for example here: [link](http://themetrust.com/demos/filtered/)

Comment: 26 views and no solutions??? please help!!!

Comment: What do you want there exactly?

Comment: I want to be smooth fade, from a image to other, without black background. Or other auto sliding animation from right to left...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this may be a solution for you:

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/badAdviceGuy/8FzR9/1/)**

It looks like your `#slideshow-inner` CSS has the background set to black, simply change it to the color you want.

CSS:

```
#slideshow-inner {
    //current styles

    background-color: rgba(255,255,240,1);
}
```

Comment: yes, is better, than a black background... but how I can make this transition like in this [example](http://themetrust.com/demos/filtered/), fading directly from a image to other, without using background colors...

Comment: @ValeriCrudu, in your example, the portfolio is using the [flexslider plugin](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) why not use that?